# Problem while taking screenshot in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, screenshot, gnome-screenshot, print-screen

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. In this system, while I want to take a screenshot of my entire screen of laptop, press <kbd>prt sc</kbd> key, then the photo is automatically saved in Picture folder. No option appears asking for File Name and for where to Save.

But these options are available in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. My question is that can I get the option that will ask for a File name and where to save option each time?

Comment: @pomsky Maybe my question is assumed to be duplicate. But the procedure is shown in the question is not working . Still no pop-up appears .

Comment: Then perhaps edit your question with details, such as *which* of the 7 answers you followed, *which exact steps* you took, *how exactly* it's failing etc.